# Angularjs post giving internal server error

Tags: angularjs, post

I have a form submit which works fine in my local environment. But on a server it gives internal server error with error code 500 .I am not sure what i am doing wrong. It was working in the previous build. Please someone tell me work around this .

```
carrierFactory.addCarrier=function(data){
    return $http.post($rootScope.contextPath +"/carrierMaster/add",data);

    };
```

This code works fine in my local environment i.e Localhost. But in the server build it fails

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method =RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Content-Type=application/json", consumes = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody CarrierMasterFormBean addCarrier(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model, @RequestBody(required=false) CarrierMasterFormBean carrierMasterFormBean, Principal principal)
```

Please Help me.

Comment: as you said, your error is server side, so how can we help us if you don't explain more ?

Comment: You should append the `.error()` function for more infos: `post(url, data).error(function(data, status, headers, config) { // ... log, trace, alert, whatever... });`. See also https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: one more weird issue is when i use input type button , i get the error post not supported, but when i use button type=button. my request is success . something to with html5 tag i believe